# what will be the time complexity of the following procedure?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, time-complexity

```
flag=true
for x=1 to n do
{
  for i=1 to n do
  {
    for j=1 to n do
    { 
      if flag=true then
      {
        for m=1 to k do
        {
          for l=1 to k do
          {
            some statements.... taking constant time
          }
        }
      } 
      some other statements....taking constant time
    }
  }
  flag=false
 }
```

What will be the time complexity of the procedure? Will it be O(n^3+ (n^2)(k^2)) or O((n^3)(k^2))?

Comment: (Up to the [2nd revision](https://cs.stackexchange.com/revisions/154179/2), this looked a trick question with a somewhat tight upper bound on run time of $O(nk^4)$.)

Answer (score 0):

When flag is true, the body of the third for takes time `ak²+b`; otherwise it takes `c`. So the total running time is

```
n²(ak²+b) + (n-1)n²c + d = O(n²k² + n³).
```